# How to convert input to float with exception handling

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make sure that the user gave a valid floating point number as input.

```
run='yes'
valid='no'
x=1
while run == 'yes':
    while valid == 'no':
        x=float(input('Enter the richter scale you wish to convert:'))
        check=isinstance(x,float)
        if check == False:
            print('Invalid value, re-try:')
    valid=yes
    float(x)`enter code here`
    square=1.5*x+4.8
    e=10**square
    print(e)
    tnt=e/4.184*10**9
    print(tnt)
```

Comment: You should use `True` and `False` instead of `'yes'` and `'no'`.

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use a try, except block. Something like this:

```
x = input('Enter the richter scale you wish to convert:')
try:
    x = float(x)
except ValueError:
    print("Sorry, that's not a valid float")
```

I am deliberately leaving the call to `input` outside of the try, except so that the value can be used for debugging purposes, and so that in case `input` some how throws an exception, it's not being caught by this block. Only the conversion to `float` should be wrapped in this block.

Comment: While you're right about keeping the `try` block as small as possible, there's no scenario where `input()` can raise a `ValueError`. Not like it matters, it should still be done like you've shown, I'm just nitpicking here to make sure nobody thinks `input()` could raise a `ValueError`.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen I don't think there is a way, but I'd rather have people learn best practices early. I added that block because someone suggested an edit to my post moving `input` inside the try, except.

Comment: I agree, your way is the correct way. Just wanted to point out that, in this particular scenario, the location of the `input()` doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you so much guys really helped!

Comment: @SamBannister Great, glad I could help!